# XLSX file reading using JAVA on Linux

Tags: java, xlsx

I have a file its name is TestCase.xlsx, I want to read and parse this file on Linux using JAVA, without converting it into csv file.Is it possible to do that, if yes then which library i should use to do this thing.

Comment: you can try Apache POI.

Comment: Here's the [link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpoi.apache.org%2F&ei=p2_9U_yAGMbkuQSs64KQBQ&usg=AFQjCNEQE_9KEVu7Hw2v7-E7dCKtWIrvCw&bvm=bv.74035653,d.c2E)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using for testing, then you have add "Apache POI" jar files in order to read excel files.you can use these java code to read your excel file,

```
File excel = new File("E:\\Data.xls"); 
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1; 

int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();//reading total num of cols
String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];//allocating array based on row n col size


for (int i=0; i<rowNum ; i++)
{
    XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);

    for( int j=0; j< colNum; j++) {
        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
        String value = cellToString(cell);
        data[i][j] = value;//based on its excel location, values will be stored in seperate array
        System.out.println( data[i][j]);
        }
}
```

PS: If you are using latest version of ms excel, use "HSSF"(Horrible SpreadSheet Format) instead of "XSSF". Make sure you have mentioned right path in the program where your file is saved.

Comment: I know i can use Apache POI for this task, but is it sure that I will be able to parse the xlsx file on Linux and there will be no impact on the content, got after parsing the file?

Comment: yeah you can, it wont affect data